# (Java) Why are my JFrame y coordinates 22 points off?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, coordinates

I have used jframes before and have never had this problem, but when I set up my buffer strategy differently (which I don't fully understand and probably the cause of this), I get this problem. Whenever I output anything on my jframe, the x coordinate matches the jframe perfectly (The farthest left x pixel is 0, farthest right x is the width of the frame itself), but the y doesn't. I used a mouse motion listener to figure out that all my y outputs start 22 pixels higher than the frame is. Example:

If I were to draw any rectangle, image, or whatever to the coordinates (0,0)... The very top of my image will be cut off by exactly 22 pixels. I'm no expert of java, and I think that no-one else has had this problem proves that, but there does seem to be no cases of this happening and I've tried 2 different IDE's on 2 different computer to see if it's my machine.

I edited my code to the "core" of the problem for criticism/help:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Mouse extends JFrame implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mouse m = new Mouse();
    m.run();
}

public void run(){
        init();
        while (this.isActive()){
            repaint();
        }
}

BufferStrategy strategy;
int mPosx;
int mPosy;

public void init(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(100,100,800,600);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = null;
    if (strategy != null) {
        try {
            g2 = (Graphics2D)strategy.getDrawGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            draw(g2);
        } 
        finally { 
            g2.dispose();
        }
        strategy.show();
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
g.fillRect(580, 30, 120, 90);
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString("Mouse X: " + mPosx, 600, 70);
g.drawString("Mouse Y: " + mPosy, 600, 90);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
        this.dispose();
        break;
        }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    mPosx = e.getX();
    mPosy = e.getY();
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
mPosx = e.getX();
mPosy = e.getY();
}
}
```

Why are my y coordinates off? Can someone write this code better and with the correct y?

Answer (score 4):

You need to account for the frame's insets.  See [`Container.getInsets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getInsets%28%29).

From the Javadoc:

> `public Insets getInsets()`
>
> Determines the insets of this container, which indicate the size of the container's border.
>
> A Frame object, for example, has a top inset that corresponds to the height of the frame's title bar.

If you want to draw on a component and not have to worry about the insets, move your drawing code to a subclass of `JComponent`, and add that component to the `JFrame`.

```
final FooComponent c = new FooComponent();     // this is your custom component
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: I would also add something about that while-loop in the run() method which does not make any sense. `repaint()` should be called when the UI changes. the isActive() will return true as long as the window is Active, as soon as the users clicks on another window, the loop will exit and no longer invoke `repaint()`.